# Rectifiable Graph of Continuous Function with Infinitely Many Turning Points

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose the graph of a continuous function $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ is rectifiable. Is it possible for $f$ to have infinitely turning points? In this case I mean by turning points local maxima/minima. Does the answer change if $f$ is differentiable?

If $f$ is not rectifiable, we can just take $f(x)=x\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$ as an example. The reason I ask this is rather silly; I'm wondering if this [problem](https://www.scs.cmu.edu/puzzle/puzzle12.html) can be generalized easily to continuous curves with finite length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about $x^k\sin\dfrac1x$ with $k>2$ if $x\ne0$, $f(0)=0$? $f$ has a bounded continuous derivative, so that its graph is rectifiable.

Comment: Forgot $C^{1}$ implies rectifiable. Thanks!